# Is "for" appropriate in this context?

Tags: prepositions

This is from [a news article](https://money.usnews.com/investing/articles/de-dollarization-what-happens-if-the-dollar-loses-reserve-status) :

> The investing playbook for inflation also applies **for** fighting
> de-dollarization. That is to say that if the dollar plunges in value,
> there is likely to be a large rise in inflation within the American
> economy. In times of inflation, assets such as energy, precious metals
> and real estate tend to fare well. An investor could consider an
> allocation to these sorts of holdings not just as a hedge against a
> falling dollar, but also for the benefits they provide in times of
> inflation or geopolitical unrest.

I think "**for**" should be replaced with 'to' because 'apply' means 'be relevant to somebody/something in this context.

Am I right?

Comment: Choice of preposition in English is often *very* flexible. *This also applies <PREP> other situations* could reasonably feature ***to, for, with, in*** - and quite possibly other prepositions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.

"To" is more natural because it collocates with "apply", but the verb "apply" doesn't need a "to" phrase, so some other phrase, like a "for" phrase could be used instead.

I'll break it down a bit for clarity. The sentence without either phrase, is still good English:

> The investing playbook for inflation also applies.

The information about in what context the playbook applies is missing, but the grammar is good. Now, if we want to also add the context, we can use a "for" phrase, as this writer did. It's less common, but it's correct.

Comment: Thank you very much.